# Subtotals shows in base Currency even if I have selected another currency for payment using Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1, payment-gateway, currency, multicurrency

There are 3 currencies being used in my website, which are INR, Dollar, and AED.

My base currency is INR, but when customer proceeds for payment and selects Dollar to pay, it shows Base currency in Subtotal and also in Payment Gateway Page, it shows the base currency itself instead of Dollar(the selected currency).

Please help me out... it's very very urgent.

I have also replaced `displayBaseGrandTotal()`  to `displayGrandTotal`   but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in Magento the currency switch functionality is only a helper to let the customers get an idea of how much they will spend but **all online payment transactions are made using the Base Currency** configured for that Website.

Base Currency can be changed at Website level in `System > Configuration > GENERAL > Currency Setup` so you can assign a different Base Currency to another Website and that Website will process payment transactions in a different Currency.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i had already done this. The ting is that ,when i proceed to checkout out and the page redirects to payment gateway of CCavenue . It shows the dollar amount but don't show the currency symbol in cc avenue page .
I asked to ccavenue customer care,They asked me to check whether the checkout is posting the Currency Symbol code or not!!

i dont know the code 

please help me out in this

Comment: as far as I understand, the CC Avenue integration is a custom extension, I suggest you ask for assistance to that extension vendor